# All my files seem to have disappeared after OS X Maverick update

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-update

[image]I recently did an update on my mac Mavericks It asked me to set up an account after it installed and now all of my files, apps and software have disappeared. I've read a similar post on here where the advice has been to go into /users, and if your home sharing file is there then simply log back into that account, BUT, my computer didn't have an "account" of such before hand, no password or logging,

does this mean that all my files are lost for good? they seem to still be on there somewhere as my the same amount of memory is being used, and I can find random files from before - I just can't open them because I'm on the wrong account, is there anyway of retrieving my stuff if I didn't have an account before? 
The picture above shows what is shown in /users - "dummy" is just an account a made in an attempt to fix the issue, "katiewatts" is the account it asked me to create after it installed and "shared" which has other files in it but nothing in those files I don't think.

I'm really stuck and would like to avoid taking it for data recovery as there's nothing wrong with the computer itself, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You didn't update your Mac from iOS to OS X. It had a previous version of OS X on it. Macs don't run iOS.

Comment: Unless you choose to reformat your drive before doing a full install your files should still be on the drive. Can you open a Finder window for `/Users` (or run `ls -al /Users` in Terminal) and add a screenshot of the content?

Comment: call my silly but how do I upload a picture to this thread? I'm new to this site! when I've searched for users in finder it comes up with "shared" "dummy" (which is just an extra one I created in attempt to fix the problem) and "katiewatts" which is the new account it created when the software installed. When I log out It gives me the option to enter the "katiewatts" account or the "dummy", nothing else - if that helps! do you know how to i go about running ls -al /users in Terminal ?

Comment: I worked it out! ha, the pic has been added